# ListView is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Activity code:

```
public class ToDoList extends Activity {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);
    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    final EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    final ArrayList<String> NewItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,NewItem);
    listview.setAdapter(aa);

    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
                    NewItem.add(0, edittext.getText().toString());
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    edittext.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    }) ;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.to_do_list, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Layout XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Item" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listview">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for starters, parts of your xml are missing

Comment: why don't you call aa.add directly, rather than keeping a reference to NewItem ?

Comment: did you check that your adding code is executed?

Comment: There's two possibilities: your ListView is wirking and just not showing or your adapter's getCount() returns 0. Firstz of all I'd try to set the height of your ListView to match_parent.

Comment: changing the listview to matchparent doesnot change anything..

Comment: Maybe you should ask your question more clearly, rather than just in the subject line? Like, your code doesn't add an item to the list, is your question that the list remains empty even after you have entered text? You sure that the key you press is Dpad-center?

Comment: Don't use a custom id for the list - use the built in one `@android:id/list` so that the Activity knows which view is the list